# 入門的なループ処理について

Tags: python, python3

```py
YEAR_BEGIN = [1971,1979,1948]
YEAR_END = 2016

VAR_list = {0:'sst', 1:'precip',2:'air'}

for ivar in [i]:

    VAR = VAR_list[ivar]
    print('Variable',ivar,VAR)

    if VAR == 'precip':
        filei1 = DIR0 + VAR + '.mon.mean'+ '.nc'   
    elif VAR == 'sst':
        filei1 = DIR0 + VAR + '.mon.mean.nc'
    elif VAR == 'air':
        filei1 = DIR0 + VAR + '.mon.mean.nc'
    else:
　　　　 pass


    clim_ref_year = 1981

    if ivar = 1
        1971
    elif ivar= 2
        1979
    else:
        1948
timeskip = (clim_ref_year - YEAR_BEGIN[ivar]) * nman -1
```

VAR_listのループをまわしてそれぞれにYEAR_BEGINを割り振りたいのですがうまくいきません。解決案はございますか？

Comment: すみません、適切な質問に見えませんでした。これは、言語学習の課題か何かでしょうか？

Answer (score 1):

おそらく実行してみると、forループのところの「'i'が定義されていません。」とエラーが出ると思います。

forループをリストの要素で順番に回すときの基本文法を確認して、コードを書き直した方がいいと思います。
（VAR_list は辞書ですが、これもイテラブルなので、ループで回せます）

回答ではありませんが、回答へのきっかけになればと思います。

Answer (score 1):

提示されているコードに不明点が多すぎたので、最後に記載されている↓の部分のみ回答します。

> VAR_listのループをまわしてそれぞれにYEAR_BEGINを割り振りたいのですがうまくいきません。解決案はございますか？

こちらに関しては、MorningMushroomさんが記載されている通り、そのままforで回せますが、items()を使用することでkeyとvalueが同時に取得できるためより良いかと思います。

```py
YEAR_BEGIN = [1971,1979,1948]
VAR_list = {0:'sst', 1:'precip',2:'air'}

for k, v in VAR_list.items():
    clim_ref_year = YEAR_BEGIN[k]
```